# how to create array of an abstract class in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, abstract-class

I am trying to create a program that takes food order and prints it out. I have my base class `Food` which has a pure virtual function in it. Class Food has 2 subclass `Pizza` and `Dessert`. I am trying to make an array of `Food` in my `main` so when a customer orders `Pizza` or `Dessert`, it will be stored in the array of `Food`. But every time I try, I get an error. How should I put the two items together then if I want to use a loop to go over each item the customer ordered?
This is my code:

```
int main()
{
  Dessert d("brownie");
  Pizza p("BBQ delux");
  Food array[2] = {d,p};
}
```

This is my error message. (NOTE: `get_set_price()` and `print_food()` are my pure virtual functions which is defined in base class and implemented in the 2 subclasses)

```
main.cpp:37:14: error: invalid abstract type ‘Food’ for ‘array’
  Food array[2] = {d,p};

In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
Food.h:5:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Food’:
 class Food
       ^

Food.h:20:15: note:     virtual void Food::get_set_price()
  virtual void get_set_price()=0;
               ^

Food.h:27:15: note:     virtual void Food::print_food()
  virtual void print_food()=0; 
               ^

main.cpp:37:22: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Food’
  Food array[2] = {f,o};
                  ^
```

Comment: Use *pointers* or *references*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "C++ Standard §8.3.2/4:

    There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references." -> So no, references is not an option!

Comment: @GURKE While my comment were intended to be more generic, there's still [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) to solve that problem. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot create instances of abstract classes, but you can assign the pointers or references of concrete derived instances to pointers or references of the base class respectively.

```
int main()
{
  Dessert d("brownie");
  Pizza p("BBQ delux");
  Food* array[2] = {&d,&p};
}
```

then work with `array`

```
array[0]->print_food();
```

Answer (score 11):

You need reference semantics for that, because `Food arr[2];` tries to initialize the array with default values (which are abstract, thus not constructible).

I think `std::array<std::unique_ptr<Food>, 2> arr;` should be the most natural to use in this case.

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<Food>> arr = {
    std::make_unique<Dessert>("brownie"),
    std::make_unique<Pizza>("BBQ delux")
};
```

If you just want to loop over those two values, though, using `initializer_list` would be easiest, I suppose.

```
for (auto f : std::initializer_list<Food*>{&d,&p})
    f->commonMemberFunction();
```

Unfortunately it won't deduce the correct type from just `{}`, but a helper could be created, I suppose,

Comment: @TartanLlama [Doesn't seem to](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9f2f5417abd2bdd).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Bartek. Could you please tell me what unique_ptr is? Is it a regular pointer or does it have some other attributes.

Comment: @SafwanUllKarim it's a pointer that guarantees sole, unique ownership of the value. See [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for details.

Comment: the only issue with this is you have to make sure you deallocate the memory at the end for all those `new`s you did.

Comment: @AndreiPetre that's not a problem, since they are all stored in the smart pointers.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz thanks, didn't know about smart pointers! Ok, so in this case it's fine, it's going to delete the memory automatically when the smart pointers (thus the array) go out of scope. :)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with C++11, you can use `std::reference_wrapper` too. It's very similar to @Mykola's answer, but uses references:

```
#include <functional>  // for std::reference_wrapper

int main()
{
  Dessert d("brownie");
  Pizza p("BBQ delux");
  std::reference_wrapper<Food> array = {d, p};

  // just to see they're references, they have same memory addresses as
  // the initial variables.
  for (const Food &f : array) {
    std::cout << &f << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n" << &d << " " << &p << "\n";
}
```

Unfortunately the same restriction applies to this and to the version with pointers. You need to have local variables defined, you can't just use anonymous objects here.

This won't work:

```
  std::reference_wrapper<Food> array = {Dessert("brownie"), Pizza("BBQ delux")};
```